# Add new calculate column (Average Sales 4 last weeks) to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I've the Table:

SSID    distrProdName   distrBranchID   distrID salesQty    weekID

1,  Product, 1, 7,  1,  434,    10

2,  Product, 2, 7,  1,  223,    10

3,  Product, 1, 7,  1,  23, 11

4,  Product, 2, 7,  1,  23, 11

5,  Product, 1, 7,  1,  43, 12

6,  Product, 2, 7,  1,  12, 12

7,  Product, 1, 7,  1,  232,    13

8,  Product, 2, 7,  1,  47, 13

I want to add a new calculate column "AvSales4LastW"

In MS Excel I resolved like this:

SSID    distrProdName   distrBranchID   distrID salesQty    weekID  AvSales4LastW   code    code1   code2   code3

1;  Product 1;  7;  1;  434;    10; 108,5;  Product 17110;  Product 1719;   Product 1718;   Product 1717

2;  Product 2;  7;  1;  223;    10; 55,75;  Product 27110;  Product 2719;   Product 2718;   Product 2717;

3;  Product 1;  7;  1;  23; 11; 114,25; Product 17111;  Product 17110;  Product 1719;   Product 1718;

4;  Product 2;  7;  1;  23; 11; 61,5;   Product 27111;  Product 27110;  Product; 2719   Product 2718;

5;  Product 1;  7;  1;  43; 12; 125;    Product 17112;  Product 17111;  Product 17110;  Product 1719;

6;  Product 2;  7;  1;  12; 12; 64,5;   Product 27112;  Product 27111;  Product 27110;  Product 2719;

7;  Product 1;  7;  1;  232;    13; 183;    Product 17113;  Product 17112;  Product 17111;  Product 17110;

8;  Product 2;  7;  1;  47; 13; 76,25;  Product 27113;  Product 27112;  Product 27111;  Product 27110;

Folmula in H9: **=B9&C9&D9&F9**

Formula in I9: **=B9&C9&D9&F9-1**

Formula in J9: **=B9&C9&D9&F9-2**

Formula in K9: **=B9&C9&D9&F9-3**

AvSales4LastW(G9) = ***AVERAGE(E9;SUMIF($H:$H;$I9;$E:$E);SUMIF($H:$H;$J9;$E:$E);SUMIF($H:$H;$K9;$E:$E)) = (47+12+23+223)/4 = 76,25***

How to add a new column (AvSales4LastW) in MS SQL SERVER?
Sorry, I can't add images

Please, help me

any, idea

Thanks

Comment: Can you please describe, in words (what fields is it looking at, over what timeframe, etc.), what the calculated column is supposed to be?  I cannot follow your Excel dump.

Comment: Do you want a running / windowed average - e.g. Week 10 will include 7, 8, 9 and 10, week 11 will be 8-11, etc?

Comment: Yes, week 10 include sum sales 10, 9,8,7 and devided by 4, e.g. Sales by product 2: 13 week = 47 kUSD, 12 week = 12 kUSd, 11 week = 23 kUSD, 10 week 223 kUSD; AvSales4LastW (13 week, product 2) = (47 + 12 + 23 + 223)/4 = 76,25 kUSD (Average Sales 4 Last weeks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you will not be able to add a COMPUTED column to the table, which reasons over previous rows in the table. You can however derive the [rolling average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) using an average over a partition, ordered by the week number, such as the following:

```
SELECT *, avg(salesQty) over (partition by distrProdName order by weekID 
          ROWS between 3 preceding and current row) AS AvSales4LastW
FROM MyTable;
```

Note however that this requires a consecutive / contiguous row for each product for each week (no gaps).

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bd4a/1)

Comment: Also note that if there are earlier weeks, then it cannot return the average for four weeks. It will return the average of what is there. So if it's zero previous weeks, it will return the current week. If there is 1 previous week, it return the average of the prev week and current week. Etc...

Comment: Yes, although this should be the "correct" value for an average, e.g. if a startup company only has one month's sales data, then the monthly average for the last 6 months would have to be approximated to the only actual trading month.

Comment: StuartLC, Thanks for your help, and how to add results to existing table?

Comment: I would say the best way to do this is to simply use Stuart's code to create a view and simply run your queries on the view. There is no way to have it be a calcuated column. You could use a function like Siyual, but I have a feeling performance would be terrible. The best and simplest way is to create a view.

Comment: it's to long calculated, i've 1 mln + rows (weekly). How to optimazed this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `COMPUTED COLUMN` that references a `FUNCTION` to derive the result.  Here is a sample mockup of this working:

Test data:

```
Create Table TestComputed
(
    PK int not null identity(1,1),
    ProductName Varchar (100),
    B int,
    C int,
    Qty int,
    Wk int
)
Go

Insert TestComputed (ProductName, B, C, Qty, Wk)
Values  ('1', 7, 1, 434, 10),
        ('2', 7, 1, 223, 10),
        ('1', 7, 1, 23, 11),
        ('2', 7, 1, 23, 11),
        ('1', 7, 1, 43, 12),
        ('2', 7, 1, 12, 12),
        ('1', 7, 1, 232, 13),
        ('2', 7, 1, 47, 13)
```

Function:

```
Create Function dbo.fnGet4WeekAverage(@WeekId Int, @ProductName Varchar (100))
Returns int
As Begin
    Declare @Average Int = 0

    Select  @Average = Avg(Qty)
    From    TestComputed
    Where   Wk Between @WeekId - 3 And @WeekId
    And     ProductName = @ProductName

    Return @Average
End
Go
```

Alter Table:

```
Alter Table TestComputed Add AvSales4LastW As dbo.fnGet4WeekAverage(wk, ProductName)
```

Results:

```
Select * From TestComputed

PK  ProductName B   C   Qty Wk  AvSales4LastW
1   1           7   1   434 10  434
2   2           7   1   223 10  223
3   1           7   1   23  11  228
4   2           7   1   23  11  123
5   1           7   1   43  12  166
6   2           7   1   12  12  86
7   1           7   1   232 13  183
8   2           7   1   47  13  76
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, if you have different ProdName, Branch, City, WeekID:

function:

```
Create Function dbo.fnGet4WeekAverage(@ProductName nvarchar (150), @BranchName int, @DistrID int, @weekID Int)
Returns float
As Begin
    Declare @Average float = 0

    Select  @Average = Avg([salesQty])
    From    [dbo].[weeklySalesStocks]
    Where   [weekID] Between @weekID - 3 And @weekID
    And     [distrProdName] = @ProductName
    And     [distrBranchID] = @BranchName
    And     [distrID] = @DistrID 

    Return @Average
End
Go
```

alter table:

```
Alter Table [dbo].[weeklySalesStocks] Add AvSales4LastW As dbo.fnGet4WeekAverage([distrProdName], [distrBranchID], [distrID], [weekID])
```